# How to reduce size of bibliography header

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

I want to reduce the amount of space that the title of my bibliography takes up. I've tried using negative vspace, albeit unsuccessfully.

My current MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,oneside,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pinlabel}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{nicefrac}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}    
\usepackage{nicefrac}   
\usepackage{float}   
\usepackage[small,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}   
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}   
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{supertabular}   
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{array}   
\usepackage{bpchem}    
\usepackage{setspace}     
\usepackage[super,sort&compress,comma]{natbib}    
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,top=3.5cm,right=3cm,bottom=3.0cm,head=0.5cm,foot=0.5cm]{geometry}    
\usepackage{subfig}   
\usepackage{balance}    
\usepackage{hyperref}    
\usepackage{chngcntr}   
\usepackage{wrapfig}    
\usepackage{chemscheme}     
\usepackage[font={scriptsize}]{caption}    
\usepackage{enumerate}    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.\cite{Solovyev05} 

\section{Middle}
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit.\cite{Forster60}

\section{Conclusion}
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci veli.\cite{Shinoda10}

\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\scriptsize       
\bibliography{Bibio}
\bibliographystyle{rsc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have left all my packages there as I wasn't sure which were giving the specific formatting of the Bibliography.

Comment: As you will see, the bibliography is summoned to appear on a new page, as desired, but it creates a large title. How do I reformat the title to be much smaller? Or to not exist at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to reduce the size of the bibliography title.

Based on your code, you just have to add:

```
\renewcommand\bibname{\scriptsize References}
\scriptsize       
\bibliography{Bibio}
\bibliographystyle{rsc}
```

If you don't want the name "References" to appear, then just type:

```
\renewcommand\bibname{}
\scriptsize       
\bibliography{Bibio}
\bibliographystyle{rsc}
```

If you want to reduce the space between the title "References" and the first entry, then type:

```
\renewcommand\bibname{References \vspace*{-10mm}}
\scriptsize       
\bibliographystyle{rsc}
\bibliography{Bibio}
```

I have arbitrary chosen -10mm, but you can set it as much as you want.